# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/SED/resources/views/reports/log_print.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

This error comes in the live environment when getting a log report. And not for all the reports but for some reports

This is my `participateOfficersArray` in the controller:

```
array_push($participateOfficersArray, [
    'officer_id'       => $officer_id,
    'officer_name'     => $officer_name,
    'officer_position' => $officer_position,
    //''date' => $participateOfficer->officer_dates,
    'date'             => $officerDaysArray,
]);
```

this is blade file:

```
@foreach($participateOfficersArray as $participateOfficersArray)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$participateOfficersArray['officer_id']}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editable">{{$participateOfficersArray['officer_name']}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editable">{{$participateOfficersArray['officer_position']}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                @foreach($participateOfficersArray['date'] as $officerDaysArray)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$officerDaysArray}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why have you named the `value` variable of the `foreach` the same as the array you're iterating over? Please can you also all the code for the controller method and  show the code for `$officerDaysArray` if it's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

try this:

```
@foreach($participateOfficersArray as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$item['officer_id']}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editable">{{$item['officer_name']}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editable">{{$item['officer_position']}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                @foreach($item['date'] as $officerDaysArray)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$officerDaysArray}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It is not working.still gets that error message

Comment: Please can you add an explanation about why this should solve the problem so that it can potentially help other people that come to this question.

Comment: one problem is here: @foreach($participateOfficersArray as $participateOfficersArray) 
these two names shouldnt be same